# Resizing Border control

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I've got controls strewn around a `Canvas` that the user can manipulate, and I'd like to make it so that the user can resize these controls by dragging a border edge. I could write a custom control, but before I dive into that, I'd like to find out if anyone has solved this problem already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the best implementation i have ever seen. Using an adorner overlay of thumps and the thumbs does the resize on the AdornedElement

http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!144.entry